# gradle: invoke a grade file under another project

Tags: gradle

Gradle 5.4.1

```
/project-foo/build.gradle


/project-bar/settings.gradle   
/project-bar/common-gradle/build-hello.gradle
/project-bar/common-gradle/build-world.gradle
```

project-bar/common-gradle is not a project directory but contains commonly used gradle files only.

project-foo/build.gradle invokes the build-hello.gradle that is under project-bar as followings:

```
task build_hello(type: GradleBuild) {
    dir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/build-hello"
    buildFile = file("/project-bar/common-gradle/build-hello.gradle")
    ...
}  

assemble.dependsOn build_hello
```

When building project-foo, error:

```
Build file '/project-bar/common-gradle/hello.gradle' is not 
part of the build defined by settings file
'/project-bar/settings.gradle'. If this is an unrelated build, 
it must have its own settings file.
```

If /project-bar/settings.gradle is removed, building project-foo works. What does the error message means?

Should a settings.gradle be created under the common-gradle directory that is not a project directory? what is its content?